# Image Hash-value on twitter (q-anon conspiracy)

Tags: security, twitter, hashcode

Ok some of you might have heard about Q-anon lately. If not no problem. Most people dismiss this as conspiracy theory anyway and I don't want to speculate here whether there is something underlying it or not.

Here the theory in short form: 
Q is a user who has started posting internal information from the american government on 4chan. Allegedly he/she is on the high administrative level of the trump government and as such has access to secret information ... ;)

Good, but that's not what it's supposed to be about. We're here on a computer science forum!

There's one thing that has puzzled me about Q. On November 8, 2017 Trump made a tweet with a picture. Pictures are stored on twitter under the address https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ + any ... I guess times hash-value. The interesting thing about this picture is that this hash value starts exactly with the letters "DOITQ", i.e. "Do it Q". The whole thing has naturally led to a series of speculations. It can of course be a coincidence, but it happened just 1-2 months after it started with Q...

here is the twitter link: https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/928325667556548608

and here is the imgurl: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DOITQJ8UIAAowsQ.jpg

I really don't want to discuss conspiracy theories here. My question actually refers exclusively to twitter:

does anybody here have an idea how the pictures of twitter are saved? I thought something like that would be done with hash values...
Can anyone imagine if or how it could be possible to manipulate these addresses...?

all opinions and ideas are welcome :)